# How can i do arithmetic operations in one TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, integer-arithmetic

For example i write in `TextBox1`

`4*5` or `3-2`

how can make the answer appear in the same textbox ?

I tried this but it did not work anyway

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 textbox1.text = val(textbox1.text)
end sub
```

it just shows the first number

Comment: Would be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net

Comment: ok so you mean you will type 4*5 in textbox and on button click event you expect answer to be 20 in same textbox?

Comment: Yes exactly and any other Calculations

Comment: You have to parse the text and do the math.

Answer (score 4):

This is a rather complex task for which there is no built-in support in the VB.NET language.  The first step is to parse the text into an [expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_tree).  The second step is to evaluate that expression tree to determine the result.  The task is certainly an advanced one for beginners, but rather than doing it yourself, there are a couple other options.  You could use an existing third-party library which does all of the heavy lifting for you, such as the free open-source [NCalc library](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).  Or, you could use [.NET's CodeDom classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to dynamically build the expression as a .NET library and then call it to get the result.